# cache path variable in config.yml for symfony2

Tags: symfony

I was looking to add a separate sub-directory to cache directory for one of the services.

What is a default cache path variable (%cache%) for symfony2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasnt easy to find but its `%kernel.cache_dir%`